# Querying ContentVersion or ContentDocument for User Other Than Owner - Only One Record At a Time?

Tags: apex, chatter, feeditem, contentversion, contentdocument

My issue is that I can't seem to query more than one record at a time from the ContentVersion or ContentDocument if I'm not the owner of the file.  Here is what works for me:

```
    Map<Id,ContentVersion> docIds = new Map<Id, ContentVersion>();
    for(Id curId : versionIds)
    {
        List<ContentVersion> cDoc = [select Id,ContentDocumentId
                                     From ContentVersion 
                                     Where Id = :curId ];
        for(ContentVersion cd :cDoc)
            docIds.put(cd.Id, cd);
    }
```

Here are various things I tried:

1. Get it from a for loop:

   ```
    List<ContentVersion> cDoc = [select Id,ContentDocumentId 
                                From ContentVersion 
                                Where Id in :versionIds ];

    for(ContentVersion cd :cDoc)
          docIds.put(cd.Id, cd);

    for(ContentVersion cd : [select Id,ContentDocumentId 
                             From ContentVersion 
                             Where Id in :versionIds ])
          docIds.put(cd.Id, cd);
   ```
2. Get it as a Map query:

   ```
   Map<Id,ContentDocument> docIds 
        = new Map<Id, ContentDocument>([select Id,LatestPublishedVersionId
                     From ContentDocument 
                     Where LatestPublishedVersionId in :versionIds ]);
   ```
3. Same this, but broken out into a look, JIC the last one was having issues:

   ```
   Map<Id,ContentDocument> docIds = new Map<Id, ContentDocument>();
   {
       List<ContentDocument> cDoc 
             = [select Id,LatestPublishedVersionId
                From ContentDocument
                Where LatestPublishedVersionId in :versionIds ];

       for(ContentDocument cd :cDoc)
           docIds.put(cd.LatestPublishedVersionId, cd);

   }
   ```

So in all of these 3 queries, nothing comes back if I'm not the owner.

I'm wondering two things:

1. Is there a way to do this without resorting to selecting one record at a time?
2. Why does this work like it does?

Comment: What is the sharing level for the class invoking the queries? A shot in thr dark but this may be the result of sharing enforcement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this - There is no default sharing for an organization, so you have to add a record for it.  If you wanted to share everything, you'd add a ContentDocumentLink record for the Org ID.  Here is example code of doing that for all ContentDocuments:

```
Id orgId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();

List<ContentDocumentLink> existingCDL = 
     [SELECT Id, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId, ShareType, Visibility 
      FROM ContentDocumentLink Where LinkedEntityId = :orgId];

Set<Id> alreadyLinked = new Set<Id>();
for(ContentDocumentLink cd : existingCDL)
    alreadyLinked.add(cd.ContentDocumentId);

List<ContentDocumentLink> cdl = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
for(ContentDocument cd : [Select Id From ContentDocument])
{
    if(! alreadyLinked.contains(cd.Id))
        cdl.add(new ContentDocumentLink(
             LinkedEntityId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId(), 
             ContentDocumentId=cd.Id, 
             ShareType = 'C', 
             Visibility = 'AllUsers'));
}
insert cdl;
```